# default params for flask api routes

Tags: python, flask

Is there a way to give a GET route default params in python Flask API?

for example:
I have this route: `GET user?fields=...` and I can pass params with `fields` that I want to get from this model (username, email and etc) and if I don't pass this `fields` param it will get a default fields for the user that I will define in the route.

**EDIT**::
and is there a way to do it in POST requests

Comment: `request.args.get('fields'[, default=None])`

Comment: @Sraw what about POST?

Comment: `request.form.get('fields'[, default=None])`

Answer (score 0):

```
@app.route("/user", defaults={'fields': your_default_value})
@user.route('/user/<fields>')
def user(fields): # it will take this default is don't pass
                                     # parameter
```

If you will not pass the fields parameter it will take your default value.

**Solution 2:**

If you are submiting your form with get method you will have a request object in your action method

```
request.args.get('id') # here you can replace id with your field, 
                       # using this you can access all your fields
```

If you are submitting your form with post request you can do following

```
request.form['code'] #this how you will get access to your form fields in post method
                     #you can change code with your form field
```

Comment: what is @user.route('/user/<fields>') ? and i don't what to pass it in the URL I want to pass it as params only

Comment: Are you submitting a form with get or post method? if you arem, then you can use the above function with your field name of form

Comment: if I send them with post and JSON format?

Comment: then you can do the following: jsonRes = request.get_json() and then to access the fields you can do it by jsonRes['you_field_name'] for that you have to import json from flask